# How to hide specific cells a VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba, function

[image: my cells]

I have the topics `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` which don't have any functionality. And as you can see, the cells *A5* and *A6* from `test1` plus *A12* and *A13* from `test2` are **empty**. How can I create a function which toggles the visibility of those empty cells after clicking on my command button?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Sub toggggle()
With Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
End With
End Sub
```

The first time, it **hides** the rows.  The second time, it makes them visible.

Comment: @Gray's Student thanks , that works great ! But let's assume I have empty cells in _A12_ _B12_ _C12_ how can I fix something like this ? :-)

Comment: Very cool GS!!!